# How to extract text with cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape some text from a website with NodeJS & Cheerio. I have tried alot of solutions found on the internet, but my result is always empty.

Website I'm trying to scrap:
https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/dumbbell-bench-press

Relevant HTML code:

```
<div class="ExDetail" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ExerciseAction">
   <section class="ExDetail-section ExDetail-meta flexo-container flexo-start flexo-between">
        <div class="grid-8 grid-12-s grid-12-m">
          <h2 class="ExHeading ExHeading--h2 ExDetail-h2" itemprop="name">
            Dumbbell Bench Press
          </h2>
        </div>
```

I'm trying to get the text: Dumbbell Bench Press

But I've tried everything I could lol..

My current code:

```
request(url, function(error, response, html) {

  if (!error) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    var name = $('h2.ExHeading.ExHeading--h2.ExDetail-h2').text();
    console.log(name);

    var json = {
      name: name
    };

    res.send(json);
  }

});
```

**EDIT:**
Added link I'm trying to scrap.

Comment: Okay it works when I literally copy/paste the html into the cheerio.load(). I will update my post with the link, where I'm trying to scrap from. If I load that link into cheerio.load(), then it doesnt work...

Comment: Probably that text is added using javascript. If that so you'll need to find another way to scrape that text

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir ah okay that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Just checked the website and my assumption seems to be wrong. Can you check if `html` is valid? Write it to a file and check if that `h2` element exists and its text is there.

Comment: You're getting blocked. You need to fake the user agent.

Comment: @pguardiario Oh that worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: Adding a fake user agent in the header fixed the problem!